# Identifying Coordinates of boundary using regionprops and finding curvature in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am a newbie in Image Processing using Matlab. I have been trying to follow this thread - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264686. I have been successful in doing edge detection and also generating the PixelList arrays. I get three arrays after I run the code. This is the code I used:

```
clear all;
A = 'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\1.tif'; 
B = imread(A,'tif');                  
B = double(B)/256;
BW = edge(B,'sobel');
imshow(BW);
L = bwlabel(BW); 
STATS = regionprops(L,'PixelList');
```

I am not able to identify the coordinates of a particular point on the image( of a bubble) using the data I have in those arrays. How should I proceed in order to get the curvature of the boundary? I couldn't follow the thread that I posted before clearly. It would be helpful if someone explains it better since I am a newbie.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the details of the image you are using, but perhaps using more of the analysis available through `regionprops`.
For example if you have roughly elliptical objects, you could use `majoraxislength` and `minoraxislength` properties to determine curvatures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have attached the image I am using below. How can I use majoraxislength and minoraxislength properties to determine curvature? I want to determine the curvature at a point both inside and outside the bubble. Is that possible with your method? Thanks in advance!


 http://i.imgur.com/p3WAE.png

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, the [curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) is the reciprocal of the radius for a circle, so for a curve in general this can be calculated by calculating the [osculating circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle)  , right? So you can use [this answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070501195929AAGu1vF) to link that to the case for an ellipse.

Comment: Or alternatively (and hopefully equivalently) you can use the parametric equation for an ellipse and the exact definition of curvature (see link in previous comment) to get an expression for the curvature.